# Typecasting error in StoredProcedure results using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a procedure which tries to return a list of Strings from DB using Hibernate

```
public List<String> getErrorMessage(int incidentID){
    List<String> returnObj = new ArrayList<String>();
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("dbo.DisplayMessage")
                                           .registerStoredProcedureParameter("IncidentID", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                                           .setParameter("IncidentID", incidentID);

    boolean status = storedProcedure.execute();
    List<Object[]> storedProcedureResults = storedProcedure.getResultList();
    if(storedProcedureResults==null || storedProcedureResults.size()==0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    for(Object[] row: storedProcedureResults) {
        returnObj.add((String)row[0]);
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

However, I get an error saying -

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

The stored procedure only returns a list of strings. How do I return it back in the function?

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? Which line? Is it a compile-time error or an exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is a run time error. It comes at line - for(Object[] row: storedProcedureResults)

Comment: Please update the question to indicate that. It suggests that `storedProcedure.getResultList()` is really returning a list of strings, so you could probably just change the code to return it directly.

Comment: Please take the object and iterate the object List and please the values in corresponding bean and return the beans  List.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes - I thot of trying that.. hold on - checking

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup - that worked. So it there is only one column being returned, i should use the list of those objects in column?

Comment: @JonSkeet if you write up the answer, Ill upvote it :)

Comment: If it returns the list of String why are you receiving it in list of object array.
Should not you write:
    List<String> storedProcedureResults = storedProcedure.getResultList();